# Modal appears only once after the user first login using localStorage Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to have a condition in displaying the modal. The condition is that the modal will appear if the day is not more than 90 days, the user has logged in, and checks whether the modal has ever appeared or not.

`emailName` I got it from the logged in user's email, it's dynamic. So, if `emailName === ''` user is not logged in.

I have an example. **User A** logged in for the first time, then the modal will appear. When **User A** logged in back, the modal does not appear.

When **User B** logged in, the modal will appear. But when **User B** logged in back, the modal doesn't appear.

The problem I'm facing is, in one device, **User A** is logged in and modal appears. When **User A** has logged out and logged in back, the modal does not appear. Likewise if **User B** is logged in. But, when I try to login again with **User A**, the modal appears, it shouldn't happen. The problem is because in `localStorage`, the value of **User A** has been replaced with **User B**.

How to solve this? is it necessary to use an array to hold all the emails that have been logged in? and how to implement it?

```js
const startDate = new Date('8/13/2021');
const endDate = new Date();
const diffTime = Math.abs(endDate - startDate);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
const emailName = '@if(!isNull(tctx.getActor().getEmail())){@tctx.getActor().getEmail()}';
                
console.log(endDate)
console.log(diffTime)
console.log(diffDays + " days");
                
if(diffDays <= 90 && emailName !== ''){
    console.log('below 3 month, logged')
                    
    const popupShow = localStorage.getItem('popupShow');
    const emailLogged = localStorage.getItem('emailVal')

    if(!popupShow || emailLogged !== emailName){
       localStorage.setItem('popupShow', true);
       localStorage.setItem('emailVal' , emailName)
       $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show')
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Solved With This Script**

```
window.onload = function() {
    (function() {
        const startDate = new Date('7/13/2021');
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const diffTime = Math.abs(currentDate - startDate);
        const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        const emailName = '@if(!isNull(tctx.getActor().getEmail())){@tctx.getActor().getEmail()}'; 
                    
    if(diffDays <= 90 && emailName !== ''){ 

        const emailLogged = localStorage.getItem('emailLogged');

        if(emailLogged === null){
            localStorage.setItem('emailLogged', '[]') 
        }

        const oldEmailLogged = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emailLogged'))
        const arraySameValue = oldEmailLogged || [];

        if(arraySameValue.indexOf(emailName) == -1){ 

            arraySameValue.push(emailName) 
            const stringRepresentingArray = JSON.stringify(arraySameValue);
            window.localStorage.setItem("emailLogged", stringRepresentingArray);
                            
            $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show'); 
        }
      }
   })();
};
```

Comment: store the users as an object in the localstorage. `{user1: true, user2: false}` then check whether to show modal or not

Comment: the user is not 2, i just give an example with 2 users. What if there are many users? maybe millions? @boxdox

Comment: you can have multiple properties inside JS Objects. `user1` and `user2` here represents a unique identifier for that user. You can store million users as well, you're only limited by storage space of localStorage, which is 5mb i think.

Comment: ahh ya, I mean not millions but maybe dozens because this is for 1 device. And it is impossible for 1 device to login with different accounts above 20. So, how is the implementation of the code that I have made? @boxdox